# Get grid view row count by css class name

Tags: jquery

I want to get gridview row count using Jquery, but row count must be only of those row which having css class name 'R1' or 'R2' in side grid.

Please suggest me how I can get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var len = $('#gvCartItems').find('.R1, .R2').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('#gvCartItems .r1').length;
var b = $('#gvCartItems .r2').length;
var c = a+b;
alert(c);
```

is one way I suppose.

Comment: But it will return all rows count in side page. i need only for any specific grid. for example grid client id is "gvCartItems"